# Rutina python para mover archivos de carpeta a carpeta

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo que separar 25,000 archivos de una carpeta, basándome en sus nombre, el cuál es una cadena única para cada archivo Ejemplo "acdg-1233-cf34-45hg.xml"

Los archivos pertenecen a dos lugares diferentes cede1 y cede2, en un excel está identificado que archivo pertenece a qué lugar. Es decir "archivo 1,cede 2", "archivo 2,cede 1" ...... "archivo 25k, cede1"

Mi idea fue obtener la lista de archivos de la cede 1 y apartir del excel dónde los identifican eso fue sencillo.

Con os.listdir cargue la lista de archivos de la carpeta donde están los 25k. Y el plan era con un for y un if comparan los nombres de los archivos, entre ambas listas, si hallaba un coincidencia con shutil mover el archivo a otra ubicación.

Cómo talvez ya intuyeron mi conocimiento en phyton no es muy bueno.

Podrían ayudarme a solucionar mi problema por favor. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Primero deberias redactarla porque esta dificil entender lo que pides. tambien te falto el codigo que has usado. tambien te falto mostrar una imagen del formato del excel ya que dpeendiendo de como estan distribuidos los datos en la hoja la solucion cambiara.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre es:

1. cargar el excel a python con pandas pandas.read_excel()
2. cargar el listado de archivos con os.listdir
3. usar un for para recorrer la lista con los nombres de los archivos
4. usar la variable del for como filtro de columna de pandas para acceder a la
   carpeta que le corresponde
5. guardar el nombre de la carpeta en una variable
6. finalmente, mover el archivo original desde su ubicacion de inicio hacia la
   carpeta de destino indicada en el excel usando la variable que
   contiene su nombre

```
### inicio del codigo
# se cargan los paquetes
import pandas as pd   # pandas para abrir el excel y almacenar los datos
import os             # os para listar los archivos 
import shutil         # shutil para mover los archivos de una carpeta a otra

direccion_actual = os.getcwd()
print(direccion_actual)   # se imprime la ubicacion del programa para referencia

# se carga el archivo excel, sin cabecera, renombrandolas y asumiendo dos columnas en una sola hoja
DF = pd.read_excel( nombre_del_excel, header = None, names=["archivo","carpeta_final"],index_col= None) 

carpeta_de_archivos = r"pone tu dir de carpeta aqui"
lista_archivos = os.listdir(  carpeta_de_archivos)

# dentro de la string debe ir la direccion de tu carpeta
# no se debe borrar la r que anteceda la string!!

carpeta_origen = r"pone tu dir carpeta aqui"
carpeta_destino = r"pone tu dir carpeta aqui" 
for nombre_archivo in lista_archivos:                                        # se accede a cada nombre de la lista
     nombre_carpeta_destino = DF[DF["archivo"] = nombre_archivo]["carpeta"]  # se busca el nombre en el data frame y se accede a la celda de la columna carpeta
     direccion_origen_archivo = carpeta_origen + "\\" + nombre_archivo       # aqui se crea la direccion de origen del archivo
     shutil.move(direccion_origen_archivo ,carpeta_destino )                 # se realiza el traspaso del archivo de una carpeta a otra.

### fin del codigo
```

**Aclaraciones y sugerencias:**

1. Este codigo esta creado para su uso en windows ya que se usa el
   caracter "" como separador en las direcciones
2. Este codigo requiere que las carpetas de destino de los archivos
   existan con antelacion
3. Debido a que no se especifico la estructura del libro excel que
   contiene los datos, se asume un libro excel con todo su contenido en
   la primera hoja con dos columnas sin cabecera ni columna de
   identificacion.
4. Se antecede un letra "r" a las strings que contienen las
   direcciones de las carpetas para que python interprete el caracter
   "" explicitamente y no como un comando, de otra forma, no
   funcionara.
5. Te recomiendo tener un respaldo de los 25mil archivos por si el
   programa falla y no tener que estar devolviendolos a mano para cada
   ejecucion del codigo.
6. Para saber la direccion de tus carpetas rapidamente lo que te
   sugiero es que abras la carpeta en cuestion y hagas click en la
   barra horizontal larga que contiene la direccion que se encuentra en
   la parte de arriba, al clickear, esta se resaltara y con el comando
   ctrl+c podras copiarla inmediatamente y podras pegarla en el
   correspondiente lugar del codigo con el comando ctrl+v
7. el programa arrojara error si lo ejecutas cuando tienes el archivo
   excel abierto o alguno de los archivos abiertos.
8. El programa arrojara error si la carpeta de destino u origen no
   existen.

finalmente, el programa puede ser mas robusto si consideramos otras condiciones para sobrepasar errores. pero esto despues de ver que funcione lo esencial.

para la proxima recuerda adjuntar mas informacion sobre tu codigo, el formato de tus datos de entrada y las funciones que deberia ejercer tu codigo